# Clone branch to different folder in Github

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone

Can I clone different branch to different folder in my local computer in github ?

And can I see notification if any contributor request a pull to master branch or my branch

Comment: Please be clearer in your question using correct formatting, spelling, tags. I recommend reading: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new firectory and clone the project to the new folder.

You will have to pull/push every change to synchronized them both.

In git 2.5 and above you can use worktree

```
git worktree add second_path
```

And now the two psth share the same repo.